# Как можно получить slice с помощью аргументов функции?

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы, list

Я знаю про метод `__getitem__`, но как получить то же самое, используя аргументы? 
То есть, вместо:

```
s = Slice(data)
s[0:1]
```

сделать так:

```
s = Slice(data)
s(0, 1)
```

Я делал такое с словарями, но оно не подходит:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import getitem

def get_slice(obj, *args):
    collect = []
    for i in range(len(args)):
        if isinstance(args[i], (list, tuple)):
            collect.append(reduce(getitem, args[i], obj))
            print(collect)
        else:
            print(reduce(getitem, args, obj))
```

Comment: `s(0, 1)` -- это `__call__`. Кст, а сам объект класса, который выглядит как функция называют функтором

Comment: чем встроенное `slice(1)` не подходит?

Answer (score 2):

> сделать так:
>
> ```
> s = Slice(data)
> s(0, 1)
> ```

Чтобы использовать круглые скобки `()` у объекта как у функций, нужно переопределить метод [`__call__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__).

Пример:

```
class MyList(list):
    def __call__(self, a, b):
        return self[a: b]

my_list = MyList([1, 2, 3, 4])
print(my_list)        # [1, 2, 3, 4]
print()

print(my_list[1: 3])  # [2, 3]
print(my_list(1, 3))  # [2, 3]
```